# How to test view controller with XIB file using Quick?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xib, nimble

I'm using Quick library for unit testing.

I'm trying to test `ViewController`, view of which is made as `XIB`.

I connected view with file owner, and view component with view controller.

And for `viewDidLoad` test, I accessed view to trigger `viewDidLoad()`.

Here's my code.

```
override func spec() {
    super.spec()

    var sut: QuestionViewController!

    describe("viewDidLoad") {
        afterEach {
            sut = nil
        }
        beforeEach {
            sut = QuestionViewController(question: "Q1")
            _ = sut.view
        }

        it("renders question header text") {
            expect(sut.headerLabel.text).toEventually(equal("Q1"))
        }
    }

}
```

But when run the test, nothing happens with just 'test fail'.
I setup break point inside spec(), but it just pass through.(nothing happens)

After removing xib file and make UI components programmatically, the test finally succeeded.

How to test `ViewController`(viewDidLoad etc.) that contains xib file when using `Quick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in your `QuestionViewController` init you have similar code to this:

```
init(question:String) {
    //do something with a question
    super.init(nibName:"QuestionNibFileName", bundle: nil)
}
```

And this is working fine in your main target but doesn't work in test, because here default bundle is different. You should use `Bundle(for:type(of:self))` so the code should look like this:

```
init(question:String) {
    //do something with a question
    let bundle = Bundle(for:type(of:self))
    super.init(nibName:"QuestionNibFileName", bundle: bundle)
}
```